# Python test andela

Tags: python

HST2: OBJECT ORIENTED PROGRAMMING LAB
Create a class called ShoppingCart.

Create a constructor that takes no arguments and sets the total attribute to zero, and initializes an empty dict attribute named items.

Create a method add_item that requires item_name, quantity and price arguments. This method should add the cost of the added items to the current value of total. It should also add an entry to the items dict such that the key is the item_name and the value is the quantity of the item.

Create a method remove_item that requires similar arguments as add_item. It should remove items that have been added to the shopping cart and are not required. This method should deduct the cost of the removed items from the current total and also update the items dict accordingly.

If the quantity of an item to be removed exceeds the current quantity of that item in the cart, assume that all entries of that item are to be removed.

Create a method checkout that takes in cash_paid and returns the value of balance from the payment. If cash_paid is not enough to cover the total, return "Cash paid not enough".

Create a class called Shop that has a constructor which takes no arguments and initializes an attribute called quantity at 100.

Make sure Shop inherits from ShoppingCart.

In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by one.

`# OOP Lab`

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
  def __init__(self):
    total = 0
    item = {}
    self.total = total
    self.item = item
  def add_item(item_name, quantity, price):
    cost = quantity * price
    self.total += cost
    self.item = {"item_name":quantity}
  def remove_item(item_name,quantity,price):
    cost = quantity * cost
    self.total -= cost
    for i in self.item:
        if quantity > self.item[i]:
            del self.item["item_name"]
    def checkout(cash_paid):
        if cash_paid < self.total:
            return "Cash paid not enough"
class Shop(ShoppingCart):
    def __init__(self):
        quantity = 100
        self.quantity = quantity
    def remove_item():
        self.quantity -= 1
```

`#! Error State the following:
my add_item is having four argument instead of three each time i run this code:`

Please i need help with this code, am new with python, i will appreciate any programming angel in python to rescue me now.

Comment: Please don't just paste your homework assignments here.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Normally I try not to answer homework requests, because in general you are right they just dump their assignment. But in this case the OP did make an attempt at solving the problem, showed their work, and was fairly close to the solution, so a bump in the right direction wouldn't be unreasonable in my opinion.

Comment: you are right, @cory

Comment: Funny, i have solve 4 Lap test on my own 2 remaining, without asking for help in the platform, and if am not mistaking the platform is suppose to help solve problem... got me wondering if you have ever solve one in your life @CoryKramer u should really learn how to contribute to open source development

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it should work out just fine:

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
        self.total += quantity * price
        if type(item_name) == str and quantity > 0:
            self.items.update({item_name: quantity})

    def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
        if quantity >= self.items[item_name] and quantity >= 1:
            items_cost = price * self.items[item_name]
            self.total -= items_cost
            del self.items[item_name]
        else:
            self.total -= quantity * price
            self.items[item_name] -= quantity

    def checkout(self, cash_paid):
        balance = 0
        if cash_paid < self.total:
            return "Cash paid not enough"
        balance = cash_paid - self.total
        return balance

class Shop(ShoppingCart):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quantity = 100

    def remove_item(self):
        self.quantity -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Class methods should accept `self` as the first argument so for example

```
def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
```

Instead of

```
def add_item(item_name, quantity, price):
```

The "4th argument" being passed is implicitly `self`, that is why the number of arguments is one higher than you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks you are great, that help eliminates the error, but still have another one coming................... according to the test result, response code return: <code>THERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results: 


Please re-read the instructions and check your code for non-implemented features.

Make sure to complete all of them before submitting. 

Here is the relevant part of the stack trace:

KeyError('Mango',),  </code>